# Multiple WP installations using 1 database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three different URLS on the same server that need to share one WordPress 3.0.1 DB. I want to be able to add a new post from one main WP and the changes show up on the other two sites.

Is the change in config file (db table) enough?

Comment: Are the websites actually different? If there not you could just set up your vhost to point to the same wp install.

Comment: Yes, example - http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs . Make sure prefix each database correctly, and each configuration is reading **correct path**

Comment: Another suggestion - you could configure your `wp-config.php` file to [use a different configuration](http://blog.kyletraff.com/wordpress-configuration-for-multiple-environments/) depending on the installation environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you're confusing multisite and multiple Wordpress installs with one database.

Three Wordpress installs can pull from the same database. (But not "table", as you first said and I edited.) Multiple installs can work from the same database by using different table prefixes so each install doesn't collide with the other or get overwritten when the 2nd, 3rd, etc., installs get made. See [Installing Multiple Blogs « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs)

But you're asking for trouble by trying to use three different URLs unless you go Multisite and share content in a different way.

What you should do is either use three Wordpress installs with three different table prefixes on one database with [WordPress › FeedWordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/) to duplicate the content.

Or, Wordpress Multisite with three folders under one WP admin (requires a VPS with access to httpd) and [WordPress › WordPress MU Sitewide Tags Pages « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/).

Or, Wordpress Multisite with three domains under one WP admin (requires a VPS with access to httpd and DNS changes for the separate domain mapping) with [WordPress › WordPress MU Domain Mapping « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) and [WordPress › FeedWordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/) to duplicate the content.

Be aware that duplicate content will also get your SEO penalized.

And, is this question so you can bid on this Elance job?: [Have three URLS that need to share the same WP DB | Elance Job](http://www.elance.com/j/have-three-urls-that-share-same-wp-db/22091229/)